# Only allow a single selection over multiple JLists

Tags: java, jlist

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I'll try my best and did lots of research before but couldn't find an answer.

**This is my setip:**

- I have multiple JLists in a JPanel
- I have multiple of thse JPanels in my JFrame

**For example like this:**

*One JFrame has twelve JPanels with each two JLists.*

Now considering the nature of components I can select 1 item of every JList. Since I have multiple JLists per component though, I essentially can select multiple entries (or to be correct 1 entry in multiple JLists).

What I want is, that on the **JFrame**, there can only be **one selected item as a whole.**

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are the number of JLists dynamic or is this a static UI?

Comment: Are the JLists uniquely named?

Comment: Well that is quite the tricky situation! Are the sections themselves dynamic or is it just the number of JLists inside them?

Comment: The lists are uniquely named (or at least I could ensure that). 
The JPanel itself is not dynamic, but the lists inside it are. I am basically talking about the JPanels as "Months" and the JLists as a "Category" with "Expenses" in the "Month".

Comment: The JLists are dynamically added to the JPanel from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your sections are dynamic, you can still iterate over all of the `JList`s in the frame.  This is true even though the lists aren't directly added to the `JFrame`.  The solution then is to create a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) that iterates over all of the lists and calls [`list.clearSelection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection()) on each one, except for the list that triggered the selection event (which can be determined by `ListSelectionEvent.getSource()`.

Here is roughly what the ListSelectionListener implementation should look like:

```
@Override
void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    for (JPanel section : frame.getSections()) {
        for (JList list : section.getLists()) {
            if (list != e.getSource()) {
                list.clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work properly, the listener must be registered with all `JList`s in the frame.  Since the lists can change dynamically, you'll need to call [`JList.addListSelectionListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener)) whenever a new list is added to the frame.  The easiest way accomplish this depends on your code.  Hopefully you have some sort of `addSection` method that you can tack on to, but if all else fails, you can always add a [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ContainerListener.html) to whatever container the sections are placed into, and search for the lists in the component hierarchy whenever a new section is added to the container.

Comment: The problem is, I only have the possibility to iterate over the Lists of one Panel, not over all the Lists in the JFrame.

Comment: @Algram Create a small class for this like `ListGroup` so you can pass it to your panels.

Comment: Let's asume I can iterate over all Lists, then I still have the problem that I cannot determine which one of them I need to clear, because I can only ask if SOME List in the Panel has a selection.

Comment: @Algram if you can get the panels from the frame, then you can get the lists from the panels, so you can still iterate over the JLists indirectly.  As far as determining which lists to clear - the strategy is to clear all of them, except the one which the selection event just occurred on.  I added some code to help illustrate the basic strategy.

Comment: @KevinK So due to the nature of my code, it is not easily possible to get detect on my JPanel, if one of the Lists changed. At the moment it works the the extent of being able to have only a single selection per JPanel, but since I ahve multiple JPanels, I can have as many selections as I have JPanels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an IDE available right now, or I would post some sample code

As you're adding a JList to you JPanel add it to a Map, using the name of the JList as the key and the JList itself is the value.  Then when you select an item on any of your JLists, go through you map whose key is not your currently selected JList and change all of their selected index to -1.  Use the setSelectedIndex() of a JList.

```
jlist1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```